# Sorting a List based on dates

Tags: python

Below is a code which I wrote to sort the elements of a list based on certain parameters. One the parameters is a date. Now the date format is mm/dd/yy. Now if the year is the same, I dont face any problem. However, if I change the year from 2011 to 2012 of a particular element, the solution breaks down. For example it treats 03/15/2012 as earlier to 03/18/2011. How do i get over this. I know changing the date format to yy/mm/dd will give me the correct solution but I don't want to tinker with that. Plz suggest a way out.

```
from operator import itemgetter
import datetime

List=[['G1','E','03/12/2011',2],
      ['G2','E','03/10/2011',2],
      ['G3','2','03/19/2011',1],
      ['G4','2','03/15/2011',2],
      ['G6','2','03/15/2011',2]]
print List

List_expedite=[]
for element in List:
    if element[1]=='E':
        List_expedite.append(element)
print "Expedite List", List_expedite

List_non_expedite=[]
for element in List:
    if element[1]!='E':
        List_non_expedite.append(element)
print "Non-expedite List", List_non_expedite

List_expedite_sort=sorted(List_expedite, key=itemgetter(-1,-2))
print "Sorted expedite List",List_expedite_sort

List_non_expedite_sort=sorted(List_non_expedite,
                              key=lambda x: (x[-1],-int(x[-3]),x[-2]))
print "Sorted non-expedite List", List_non_expedite_sort
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
sorted(List, key=lambda x: (x[2].split('/')[2], x[2].split('/')[0], x[2].split('/')[1]))
```

For an example:

```
List=[['G1','E','03/12/2011',2],
      ['G2','E','03/10/2011',2],
      ['G3','2','03/19/2012',1],
      ['G4','2','03/15/2010',2],
      ['G6','2','03/15/2012',2]]
```

it returns:

```
[['G4', '2', '03/15/2010', 2],
 ['G2', 'E', '03/10/2011', 2],
 ['G1', 'E', '03/12/2011', 2],
 ['G6', '2', '03/15/2012', 2],
 ['G3', '2', '03/19/2012', 1]]
```

or even better (provided you did `import datetime`):

```
...
sorted(List, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%m/%d/%Y'))
...
```

Comment: Just a clarifying bit of info: as far as python knows, yiu are sorting on strings. You need to do something with that string to have python sort it otherwise, either like above (re-arranging the data) or by converting it into a date and sorting on that.

Comment: FWIW, the first could be shortened slightly to `sorted(List, key=lambda x: (lambda d=x[2].split('/'): (d[2], d[0], d[1]))())
`.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, sorting the following list

```
[('2011','03','12'),('2011','02','12'),('2011','02','10'),('2009','01','25']
```

or this one

```
[('2011','03/12'),('2011','02/12'),('2011','02/10'),('2009','01/25']
```

is equivalent.

I propose:

```
List_expedite = []
List_non_expedite = []
for element in li:
    (List_expedite if element[1]=='E' else List_non_expedite).append(element)
List_expedite.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-1], x[-2].rsplit('/',1)[::-1]))
List_non_expedite.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-1], -int(x[-3]), x[-2].rsplit('/',1)[::-1]))
```

Using **strptime()** raises considerably the execution's time, it's 16 times longer:

```
from time import clock,strptime

List = [['G1','E','03/12/2011',2],
        ['Ga','E','01/25/2009',2],
        ['Gc','E','02/11/2008',2],
        ['Ge','E','01/02/2007',5],
        ['G2','E','03/10/2011',2],
        ['G3','2','03/19/2011',1],
        ['Gb','E','01/24/2009',2],
        ['G4','2','03/15/2011',2],
        ['G6','2','03/15/2011',2],
        ['Gd','E','02/12/2011',2],]


te = clock()
for i in xrange(1000):
    List_expedite = []
    List_non_expedite = []
    for element in List:
        (List_expedite if element[1]=='E' else List_non_expedite).append(element)
    List_expedite.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-1], strptime(x[-2],'%m/%d/%Y')))
    List_non_expedite.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-1], -int(x[-3]), strptime(x[-2],'%m/%d/%Y'))) 
print clock()-te

print "Expedite List\n", '\n'.join(map(repr,List_expedite))
print

print "Non-expedite List\n", '\n'.join(map(repr,List_non_expedite))
print


te = clock()
for i in xrange(1000):
    List_expedite = []
    List_non_expedite = []
    for element in List:
        (List_expedite if element[1]=='E' else List_non_expedite).append(element)
    List_expedite.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-1], x[-2].rsplit('/',1)[::-1]))
    List_non_expedite.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-1], -int(x[-3]), x[-2].rsplit('/',1)[::-1]))
print clock()-te

print "Expedite List\n", '\n'.join(map(repr,List_expedite))
print

print "Non-expedite List\n", '\n'.join(map(repr,List_non_expedite))
print
```

result

```
3.18868152237
Expedite List
['Gc', 'E', '02/11/2008', 2]
['Gb', 'E', '01/24/2009', 2]
['Ga', 'E', '01/25/2009', 2]
['Gd', 'E', '02/12/2011', 2]
['G2', 'E', '03/10/2011', 2]
['G1', 'E', '03/12/2011', 2]
['Ge', 'E', '01/02/2007', 5]

Non-expedite List
['G3', '2', '03/19/2011', 1]
['G4', '2', '03/15/2011', 2]
['G6', '2', '03/15/2011', 2]

0.199834057122
Expedite List
['Gc', 'E', '02/11/2008', 2]
['Gb', 'E', '01/24/2009', 2]
['Ga', 'E', '01/25/2009', 2]
['Gd', 'E', '02/12/2011', 2]
['G2', 'E', '03/10/2011', 2]
['G1', 'E', '03/12/2011', 2]
['Ge', 'E', '01/02/2007', 5]

Non-expedite List
['G3', '2', '03/19/2011', 1]
['G4', '2', '03/15/2011', 2]
['G6', '2', '03/15/2011', 2]
```